# How did South Park achieve to match the outcome of the 2016 presidential election?

Tags: production, south-park

In the last episodes of South Park we all can see that Trump aka Mr. Garrison became president. This is exactly what happened in the US. I think that Matt and Trey are smart enough for a competent guess of the outcome but of course they could have just made multiple versions for every possible outcome. Does anyone know facts about that?

Comment: Most of the stuff in South Park is made up... I have a feeling they would have had "Trump" win, regardless... just for laughs.

Comment: It is well-known that SP is written in the week before it airs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6_Days_to_Air . See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Park#Production .

Comment: Simpsons did it first.

Comment: Agree with @Catija.  Matt & Trey would have written a Trump victory regardless, just to capitalize on the shock value.  They weren't trying to predict anything, they were just trying to provoke controversy (it's what they do.)  That being said they weren't the only ones predicting a Trump victory: https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-fix/wp/2016/10/28/professor-whos-predicted-30-years-of-presidential-elections-correctly-is-doubling-down-on-a-trump-win/

Comment: @Steve-O No, SP wouldn't have written a Trump victory. http://www.esquire.com/entertainment/tv/news/a50524/south-park-presidential-election-trump-win/

Comment: @BCdotWEB Looks like the answer to the question. :)

Comment: I rephrased the question title just in case. This is a very interesting question about the production process of a TV show and the ways in which it tries to match up with current events and I can't see the reasons for downvoting it so heavily. But just in case (although I don't feel it's necessary) I tried to make the title a little more formal. Anyway, +1 for a good question.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson The production process is well-known: there's a documentary about it as well as plenty or articles, and it is detailed in the wiki for the show. If OP was interested in the process he could have googled it: "How is South Park made?" gives me a link to the "6 Days to Air" wiki and an article about it. Googling "South Park Trump victory" offers plenty of useful results as well. This question lacks basic effort, simple as that.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Episode 8 was sent one day after the election. I thought it would be not possible that the content was changed so quickly so I assumed that they had the right guess at the beginning. But the facts you provided in your answer shows that they had changed the plot. This was exactly I was looking for and it doesn't show up in my research efforts 4 days ago.

Comment: @Noir This wasn't the first time they've done such a thing: https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/12ufvy/south_park_nails_obamas_victory_speech_even_the/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

South Park's production process is well-known, you'll only need to watch [the documentary *6 Days to Air*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6_Days_to_Air):

> The film follows the show's hectic, rushed six-day production schedule, in which **a 22-minute episode is completed just hours before its original air date**.

(This is a quote from Wikipedia.)

Matter of fact, for this season's first episode [they experienced a major malfunction mere hours before airtime](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/09/25/arts/television/south-park-after-two-decades-its-still-by-the-seat-of-their-pants.html):

> “Member Berries” was broadcast at 10 p.m. on Sept. 14, but hardly without last-minute incident. That morning, South Park Studios suffered a system crash, and the episode’s audio went missing for an hour and a half.
>
> When the episode was transmitted to Comedy Central, it had a mystery six-frame sync problem that was finally fixed and delivered **one hour before airtime**.

Moreover, there is evidence that [for last week's episode the makers had featured a Clinton win](http://www.esquire.com/entertainment/tv/news/a50524/south-park-presidential-election-trump-win/), with the original synopsis being:

> The new administration has plans for Gerald on an all-new episode of South Park titled **"The Very First Gentleman"** on Wednesday, November 9 at 10:00 p.m. ET/PT on Comedy Central. PC Principal tries one more time to make peace between the boys and the girls. Meanwhile, Gerald comes face-to-face with the Troll Hunter.

Note the title of the episode.

Answer (score 3):

They failed on this particular episode. They planned a Clinton victory and had to rewrite a few scenes to make it match with Trump's victory.
But for Obama's election, they had better luck back in 2008.

You can see that these episodes are written in a way that the winner can be changed quite easily. Very few scenes show or speak about who wins the election.